# How to fix "Conversion from string "August" to type 'Date' is not vaid in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT
    a.ItemCode, 
    SUM(a.NoOfApplication) AS NoOfApplication,
    SUM(a.NoOfAccomplished) AS NoOfAccomplished, 
    SUM(a.NoOfPending) AS NoOfPending,
    SUM(a.NoOfDocumentCompliance) AS NoOfDocumentCompliance, 
    a.[Year] 
FROM
    (SELECT
         ItemCode, 
         COUNT(am.ReferenceNumber) AS NoOfApplication,
         COUNT(TNA.NoOfAccomplished) AS NoOfAccomplished,
         COUNT(TNP.NoOfPending) AS NoOfPending,
         SUM(FDC.NoOfDocumentCompliance) AS NoOfDocumentCompliance,
         DATENAME(month, ad.applicationdate) AS [Year]
     FROM
         AppTypes at
     INNER JOIN
         AssessmentMainDetails am ON at.Category = am.Category 
     INNER JOIN  
         InspectionProcesses i ON am.ReferenceNumber = i.ReferenceNo
     LEFT JOIN
         (SELECT   
              COUNT(Status) AS NoOfDocumentCompliance, 
              ReferenceNumber, Status 
          FROM 
              ApplicationStatus 
          WHERE 
              Status = 'For Document Compliance' 
          GROUP BY 
              ReferenceNumber, Status) AS FDC ON FDC.ReferenceNumber = i.ReferenceNo
     LEFT JOIN 
         (SELECT   
              COUNT(ReferenceNo) AS NoOfAccomplished, 
              ReferenceNo 
          FROM 
              InspectionProcesses    
          WHERE 
              DateOfInspection <> '' 
          GROUP BY 
              ReferenceNo) AS TNA ON TNA.ReferenceNo = i.ReferenceNo
     LEFT JOIN 
         (SELECT   
              COUNT(ReferenceNo) AS NoOfPending, ReferenceNo 
          FROM 
              InspectionProcesses 
          WHERE 
              DateOfInspection = '' 
          GROUP BY 
              ReferenceNo) AS TNP ON TNP.ReferenceNo = i.ReferenceNo
     INNER JOIN 
         ApplicationDetails ad on i.ReferenceNo = ad.ReferenceNumber
     INNER JOIN 
         Companies c on ad.CompanyId = c.CompanyID
     INNER JOIN 
         Zones z on c.zonecode = z.zonecode
     INNER JOIN 
         ZoneGroups zg on z.ZoneGroup = zg.ZoneGroupId 
     WHERE 
         DateOfInspection = '' 
         AND ad.ApplicationDate BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2017-09-30' 
         AND zg.ZoneGroupCode = 'HO' 
         AND z.ZoneCode = 'VIDC'
     GROUP BY
         ItemCode, DATENAME(month, ad.applicationdate)) a
GROUP BY
    a.ItemCode, a.[Year]
```

This my code, I already converted my date to get the month name. Please I need help

Comment: What is the data type of the `month` column?

Comment: Check your string data using TRY_CAST https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen month is not a column, it  is a datepart used in DATENAME()

Comment: @Pel Tapel, where do you get this error, does the query executes without problem in SSMS?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I mean `applicationdate`, what type is that then?

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully. That giant derived table (a - nice meaningful name btw) has the same group by clause as the outermost query. So that means that [a] has a single row per ItemCode and datename(month, ad.applicationdate). Therefore, there is nothing to sum in your outer query since it is grouping by the same columns.

You also have the expression:

> DateOfInspection = ''

which is highly suspicious based on the name of the column. What datatype is the  DateOfInspection column? Doesn't sound like it should be string-based.

And lastly, the error message you posted sounds like it comes from SSRS and not sql server. Is that the case? Does your query run correctly from SSMS? Then the problem is in your report - and it would seem that you attempt to manipulate or interpret the Year column as a date (perhaps for sorting?). It also seems a bit short-sighted in your report design that your "Year" column is actually the name of a month and that your resultset does not include the year in some fashion. What happens when your data spans more than twelve months? And how do you intend to sort your report when you have month name but not month number?